# How to modify this JavaScript code to prevent unlimited zoom in

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote the html code below to display full screen image. Since my images sometimes are very large, I wanted to be able to zoom in and see the details. I found this JavaScript code here http://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/ . It works very well, but I would like to prevent unlimited zoom in. I need it to be limited by the size of the image. How can I modify the code to do that? Thanks.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Zoom</title>
<style>
html, body {
    background:#333333;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#image {
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <img class='zoom' src='MyImage.jpg' id='image'/>
    <script src="wheelzoom.js"></script>
    <script>
    wheelzoom(document.querySelector('img.zoom'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
/*!
    Wheelzoom 3.0.4
    license: MIT
    http://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom
*/
window.wheelzoom = (function(){
    var defaults = {
        zoom: 0.10
    };

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    var main = function(img, options){
        if (!img || !img.nodeName || img.nodeName !== 'IMG') { return; }

        var settings = {};
        var width;
        var height;
        var bgWidth;
        var bgHeight;
        var bgPosX;
        var bgPosY;
        var previousEvent;
        var cachedDataUrl;

        function setSrcToBackground(img) {
            img.style.backgroundImage = 'url("'+img.src+'")';
            img.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
            canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
            canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
            cachedDataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
            img.src = cachedDataUrl;
        }

        function updateBgStyle() {
            if (bgPosX > 0) {
                bgPosX = 0;
            } else if (bgPosX < width - bgWidth) {
                bgPosX = width - bgWidth;
            }

            if (bgPosY > 0) {
                bgPosY = 0;
            } else if (bgPosY < height - bgHeight) {
                bgPosY = height - bgHeight;
            }

            img.style.backgroundSize = bgWidth+'px '+bgHeight+'px';
            img.style.backgroundPosition = bgPosX+'px '+bgPosY+'px';
        }

        function reset() {
            bgWidth = width;
            bgHeight = height;
            bgPosX = bgPosY = 0;
            updateBgStyle();
        }

        function onwheel(e) {
            var deltaY = 0;

            e.preventDefault();

            if (e.deltaY) { // FireFox 17+ (IE9+, Chrome 31+?)
                deltaY = e.deltaY;
            } else if (e.wheelDelta) {
                deltaY = -e.wheelDelta;
            }

            // As far as I know, there is no good cross-browser way to get the cursor position relative to the event target.
            // We have to calculate the target element's position relative to the document, and subtrack that from the
            // cursor's position relative to the document.
            var rect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
            var offsetX = e.pageX - rect.left - window.pageXOffset;
            var offsetY = e.pageY - rect.top - window.pageYOffset;

            // Record the offset between the bg edge and cursor:
            var bgCursorX = offsetX - bgPosX;
            var bgCursorY = offsetY - bgPosY;

            // Use the previous offset to get the percent offset between the bg edge and cursor:
            var bgRatioX = bgCursorX/bgWidth;
            var bgRatioY = bgCursorY/bgHeight;

            // Update the bg size:
            if (deltaY < 0) {
                bgWidth += bgWidth*settings.zoom;
                bgHeight += bgHeight*settings.zoom;
            } else {
                bgWidth -= bgWidth*settings.zoom;
                bgHeight -= bgHeight*settings.zoom;
            }

            // Take the percent offset and apply it to the new size:
            bgPosX = offsetX - (bgWidth * bgRatioX);
            bgPosY = offsetY - (bgHeight * bgRatioY);

            // Prevent zooming out beyond the starting size
            if (bgWidth <= width || bgHeight <= height) {
                reset();
            } else {
                updateBgStyle();
            }
        }

        function drag(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            bgPosX += (e.pageX - previousEvent.pageX);
            bgPosY += (e.pageY - previousEvent.pageY);
            previousEvent = e;
            updateBgStyle();
        }

        function removeDrag() {
            document.removeEventListener('mouseup', removeDrag);
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag);
        }

        // Make the background draggable
        function draggable(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            previousEvent = e;
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', removeDrag);
        }

        function load() {
            if (img.src === cachedDataUrl) return;

            var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(img, null);

            width = parseInt(computedStyle.width, 10);
            height = parseInt(computedStyle.height, 10);
            bgWidth = width;
            bgHeight = height;
            bgPosX = 0;
            bgPosY = 0;

            setSrcToBackground(img);

            img.style.backgroundSize =  width+'px '+height+'px';
            img.style.backgroundPosition = '0 0';
            img.addEventListener('wheelzoom.reset', reset);

            img.addEventListener('wheel', onwheel);
            img.addEventListener('mousedown', draggable);
        }

        var destroy = function (originalProperties) {
            img.removeEventListener('wheelzoom.destroy', destroy);
            img.removeEventListener('wheelzoom.reset', reset);
            img.removeEventListener('load', load);
            img.removeEventListener('mouseup', removeDrag);
            img.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag);
            img.removeEventListener('mousedown', draggable);
            img.removeEventListener('wheel', onwheel);

            img.style.backgroundImage = originalProperties.backgroundImage;
            img.style.backgroundRepeat = originalProperties.backgroundRepeat;
            img.src = originalProperties.src;
        }.bind(null, {
            backgroundImage: img.style.backgroundImage,
            backgroundRepeat: img.style.backgroundRepeat,
            src: img.src
        });

        img.addEventListener('wheelzoom.destroy', destroy);

        options = options || {};

        Object.keys(defaults).forEach(function(key){
            settings[key] = options[key] !== undefined ? options[key] : defaults[key];
        });

        if (img.complete) {
            load();
        }

        img.addEventListener('load', load);
    };

    // Do nothing in IE8
    if (typeof window.getComputedStyle !== 'function') {
        return function(elements) {
            return elements;
        };
    } else {
        return function(elements, options) {
            if (elements && elements.length) {
                Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, main, options);
            } else if (elements && elements.nodeName) {
                main(elements, options);
            }
            return elements;
        };
    }
}());
```

Comment: hard to tell from just that, while we take a look, why not email the guy who made it? Pretty cool little lib there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look for

```
if (deltaY < 0) {
    bgWidth += bgWidth*settings.zoom;
    bgHeight += bgHeight*settings.zoom;
```

and change to

```
if (deltaY < 0) {
    if(bgWidth < canvas.width){
        bgWidth += bgWidth*settings.zoom;
        bgHeight += bgHeight*settings.zoom;}
```

also you should reference the javascript file in the html head tag

Comment: Thanks @Swayze, your code worked to limit the amount of zoom and I could work with that. But what I really need is for the zoom amount to be limited by the dimensions of the image. How can I prevent the image from zooming more than 100% of its width/height? My images come in different sizes.  I think what I need is - at the maximum zoom level 1 image pixel should equal 1 monitor/device pixel.

Comment: in that case forget about `maxZoom` you can remove that entirely..
just change the if statement.. the javascript already has a variable `canvas.width` for the original width... I will edit my answer

Comment: something didn’t work for me. I removed maxZoom and copied the edited code. Now I can’t zoom in at all.

Comment: maybe you removed something else by mistake..  try copying the whole code over again and then make the suggested changes

Comment: Swayze thank you so much. I did as you suggested and everything works! As you thought I must’ve accidentally made a mistake while editing the code before. Your answer as awesome, it does exactly what I was looking for and it really helped me.